# How to match all user_name with password in golang?

Tags: go

Using a struct, I'm saving the data in the JSON form to collection like so:

```
type SignUp struct {
 Id           int      `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
 UserName     string   `json:"user_name" bson:"user_name"`
 EmailId         string   `json:"email_id" bson:"email_id"`
 Password    string   `json:"password" bson:"password"`
}
type SignUps []SignUp
```

And retrieved the data from the collection of mongodb using function

```
func Login(c *gin.Context) {
 response := ResponseControllerList{}
 conditions := bson.M{}
 data, err := GetAllUser(conditions)
 fmt.Println(data)
 fmt.Println(err)
 Matching(data)
 return
}

func GetAllUser(blogQuery interface{}) (result SignUps, err error) {
 mongoSession := config.ConnectDb()
 sessionCopy := mongoSession.Copy()
 defer sessionCopy.Close()
 getCollection := mongoSession.DB("sign").C("signup")
 err = getCollection.Find(blogQuery).Select(bson.M{}).All(&result)
 if err != nil {
    return result, err
 }
 return result, nil
}
```

But the data retrieved without its keys like shown below:-

```
[{1 puneet puneet@gmail.com puneet} {2 Rohit abc@gmail.com puneet}]
```

**Issue** is that I want to collect all the existing `EmailId` and `Password`
and match them with `userid` and `password` entered by the user in fucntion given bellow:-

```
func Matching(data Signups){
  userid="abc@gmail.com"
  password="puneet"
  //match?
 }
```

How can I match the `userid` and `password` with the `EmailId` and `Password` fields?

Answer (score 1):

This is not answering your question directly, but is **very** important nonetheless. It seems that you are saving the passwords of your users in plain text in the database. This is very careless and you should add some encryption like bcrypt: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt

When you have added some encryption, your matching would be quite different than all given answers. This depends on the used encryption package. But please ignore the other answers. They might work, but only for plain text passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You can give an `if` condition to check if the userid or email is empty or not on your `Matching` function like:

```
....

if data.userid != "" {
    data.username = data.userid
} 

data.password

....
```

You can create new struct for the query and use it to create your `Matching` function.

Comment: see the data i retrieved it is without `key`.

Comment: yes you can.
On golang, if you pass the data on struct type, it wont show the key on console. you should can get the value and try to log on console.
If the data is in array, you can  map it too.

Comment: @Puneet, Println does not show field names by default. `fmt.Println(data)` is the same as `fmt.Printf("%v\n", data)`. ["when printing structs, the plus flag (%+v) adds field names"](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing).

Comment: @okay sir thank you to helping me for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for _, signup := range data {
        if userId == signup.Id && password == signup.Password {
            println("Match!")
        }
    }
```